# Ionic Cordova - undefined cannot be used as an entry compo

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to run an ionic app and i'm getting the following:

[image]

EDIT: rm -rf Node_Modules got rid of the first error:

[image]

I have a home page, another page called flashing, and a texting page. Nothing looks "off" about this code to me.

My code for app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {TextingPage} from '../pages/texting/texting';
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {FlashingPage} from '../pages/flashing/flashing';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TextingPage,
    FlashingPage
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        HttpModule,
  ],



bootstrap: [IonicApp],

  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TextingPage,
    FlashingPage,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],

  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]

})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: @Maher it doesn't work that way. Ionic2 uses Angular2 which is written in TypeScript, which is converted to JS in runtime. So the code in `main.js` you wish to see is not much human readable (at least to me.)

Comment: @NVS Abhilash 

Doing rm -rf Node_Modules removed the first error.